# get the relationship between two nodes cypher query using node

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, cypher

Here is I have done, I want get the relationship between two nodes i.e user nodes and other nodes. Here user nodes have two kinds of relationship (user) - [:knows] -> (other)
and (user) - [:friendrequest] -> (other)

I want to do the following:

1. show add friend button in view incase no relation exists between user and other,
2. show friend request sent if friendrequest relation exists between user and other
3. already friends status if knows relation exists between user and other

.actual code is this.

```
      User.checkRelationship = function (user, fid, callback) {

  var uids = [user.uid, fid];
  async.map(uids, User.by_uid, function (err, usernodes) {
    if (!err && usernodes && usernodes.length) {
      User.relsCheck(usernodes, function (err, rels) {
        if (!err && rels) {
          console.log('relationship ' + JSON.stringify(rels.data()));
          callback(null, rels);
        } else {
          callback(err || new Error('friend request exists'));
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback(err || new Error('Unable to fetch user nodes: ' + uids.join(',')));
    }
  });
};



  User.relsCheck = function (nodes, callback) {
  if (nodes.length !== 2) {
    return callback(new Error('Invalid/insufficient arguments'));
  }
  var query = [
  'START user=node({userId}), other=node({otherId})',
  'MATCH (user) -[rels?:RELTYPE]-> (other)',
  'RETURN rels'
   ].join('\n');


   var params = {
       userId: nodes[0].node().id,
       otherId: nodes[1].node().id,
    };

    db.query(query, params, callback);
    };
```

There is problem with query as well as callback
please help people, thanks!

Comment: Can you detail what the issues are ? You don't have a `callback` variable/parameter when you call `User.relsCheck(...)` and why are you using `new rels`?